# Youtube Api no result issue

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to use Youtube Api V3 to get documentaries videos, unfortunately I can't get any results for many searched keys.
Is there any advanced configuration I can use to get more results or is there any alternative API(s) ?

this is my query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=alien&type=video&videoCategoryId=35
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost make sure you have an API_KEY. Follow [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for details, then go to [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to get one. 
 Then your request URL should look like this.

```
var API_KEY = "your api key";
var channelID = "The channel id u wan to pull";
var result = 30 // Limit the number of videos
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${API_KEY}&channelId=${channelID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=${result}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but your request will only get data from a given channel. What I'm trying to do is to search by videoCategories

Comment: Hi i just assumed you wld read abit of the documentation. Here see link for all the search parameters [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list] u wld need. Change the channelId to videoCategoryId.

Answer (score 0):

With an API key, I also pulled 0 results for 'alien' in the Documentary category. Perhaps there aren't any.